# Namespace addition to i18n-ally does not work

Tags: vscode-extensions, i18n-ally

I'm using i18n-ally to see the translations whenever I translate texts and it works
but not that I added the namespace to the key it stopped working. I was wondering if there was a configuration to enable it.

I use it like this right now: `t('system.header')` //shows translation

I want to use it like this: `t('downloads:system.header')` //doesn't show translation